# limit records in cursor by using a variable

Tags: oracle

i'm not sure how to best describe my problem

i have a table (NR_POSTAL_ABBR) that has postal abbreviations and what they stand for, like ST and STREET, AVE and AVENUE. i want to be able to replace the address field with the values from that table.

if i have an address 123 Main ST i want it to say 123 Main Street. i have a procedure that does this (below). it's slow and now that i have a table with 3M records and it has to go through 400 abbreviation pairs it will run forever.

so i'm thinking of ways to speed this up. one way would be to only loop through the records that have the abbr in the Address field, so doing something like below but it doesn't work because it's in the wrong place.

so 2 part question

1. is there a better way to achieve what i'm trying to do?
2. if not then how can i fix the below procedure to be able to limit the records by only those where the address has the ReplaceWhat value from the NR_POSTAL_ABBR table

thank you

ETA the NewAddress field has addresses with .,:; replaced with spaces. this way i'm able to only replace the values if they're whole words ( st, not west)

what i'd like to replace the second CURSOR with

```
     CURSOR readMainTable IS
       SELECT A.*
         FROM analyst.NR_TMP_105 A
WHERE NeweAddress LIKE '%' || VariableThatHoldsTheReplaceWhatValue || '%';
```

the procedure i currently have and that works but is very slow

```
DECLARE
     CURSOR getReplsStrng IS
       SELECT replacewhat
          ,replacewith
         FROM analyst.NR_POSTAL_ABBR
        WHERE ReplaceOrder = 1;

     CURSOR readMainTable IS
       SELECT A.*
         FROM analyst.NR_TMP_105 A;

     lvAddress VARCHAR2(5000);
     lvTmpAddress VARCHAR2(5000);
     lnPos NUMBER(10);
     lnPosPls NUMBER(10);
     lvPosPls VARCHAR2(500);
     lvPosMinus VARCHAR2(500);
     lnLoopCnt NUMBER := 0;
     lvCty VARCHAR2(200);
     lvBfUpd VARCHAR2(500);
     lvAfterUpd VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
     lnLoopCnt := 0;

     FOR getRec IN readMainTable LOOP
       lnLoopCnt := lnLoopCnt + 1;

       lvAddress := NULL;
       lvTmpAddress := NULL;

       lvAddress := getRec.NewAddress;
       lvTmpAddress := getRec.NewAddress;

       FOR getInnerRec IN getReplsStrng LOOP
         lvPosPls := NULL;
         lvPosMinus := NULL;
         lnPos := 0;
         lnPos := INSTR(UPPER(lvAddress), UPPER(getInnerRec.replacewhat), 1, 1);

         IF lnPos > 0 THEN
              NULL;

              lvPosPls := SUBSTR(UPPER(lvAddress)
                       ,((  INSTR(UPPER(lvAddress), UPPER(getInnerRec.replacewhat), 1, 1)
                          + LENGTH(UPPER(getInnerRec.replacewhat))))
                       ,1);
              lvPosMinus := SUBSTR(UPPER(lvAddress), (INSTR(UPPER(lvAddress), UPPER(getInnerRec.replacewhat), 1, 1) - 1), 1);

              IF     (   lvPosPls IS NULL
                OR lvPosPls = CHR(32))
              AND (   lvPosMinus = CHR(32)
                OR lvPosMinus = CHR(32)) THEN
                lvAddress := REPLACE(UPPER(lvAddress), UPPER(getInnerRec.replacewhat), UPPER(getInnerRec.replacewith));

                lvAddress := LOWER(lvAddress);
              ELSIF lvPosPls IS NOT NULL THEN
                NULL;
              END IF;
              BEGIN
                UPDATE analyst.NR_TMP_105 b
                SET b.NewAddress = lvAddress
                 WHERE   b.NewAddress = lvTmpAddress
                    AND b.UniqueID = getRec.UniqueID;
                COMMIT;
              EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error in updating the address : ' || lvTmpAddress);
              END;
         ELSIF lnPos = 0 THEN
              NULL;
         END IF;

         lvTmpAddress := lvAddress;

         IF MOD(lnLoopCnt, 200) = 0 THEN
              COMMIT;
              NULL;
         END IF;
       END LOOP;
     END LOOP;

     COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error in main process:' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your second part then you can do something along the lines of

```
CURSOR readMainTable IS
   SELECT DISTINCT A.*
     FROM analyst.NR_TMP_105 A
     INNER JOIN NR_POSTAL_ABBR B
     ON (A.NewAddress like ' %'||B.replacewhat||'%'
    WHERE B.ReplaceOrder = 1
```

That should give you just the addresses that require replacements (or potentially require them - you might need to refine it).
Is there a better way?  Maybe, but how you go with this determines whether you need to put the extra effort in or not.

Comment: Omg, this is so cool. I don't know why I didn't think of this. I will test it tomorrow and reply. Even if this works, now that I think about it, it probably still won't be fast enough. So maybe I will start a different question for part 1 this way you get credit for part 2. Thank you very much

Comment: it works, it's still running (i'm making a table with your query and then will use that table in the cursor part to speed this up a little) but this will still not be fast enough. so i will repost my question if i don't figure out how to speed this up. you gave me some ideas, i didn't know i can join on a LIKE. thank you very much!!!!

Comment: for some reason it's only giving me 150 results out of the 400K that i should get (i ran a query with manually spelling out all entries, SELECT DISTINCT  address, newaddress, newaddress2
  FROM NR_TMP_105
 WHERE (   NewAddress LIKE '%lgts%'
 OR NewAddress LIKE '%lf%'
 OR NewAddress LIKE '%lck%'
 OR NewAddress LIKE '%lcks%'.....

Comment: i'm sorry, disregard, there was a space in your query before the % and i didn't notice it.