# replace only exact words with a list of words from a table

Tags: oracle

this question is a part of this one

[limit records in cursor by using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718426/limit-records-in-cursor-by-using-a-variable/19719499#19719499)

the original question was a 2 part question, 1 part being, IS THERE A BETTER WAY TO DO THIS

i have code that works but it's EXTREMELY slow, about 2 seconds for each record.

so i have a table, NR_POSTAL_ABBR, that has 2 fields and about 400 records

```
ReplaceWhat       ReplaceWith
Ave               Avenue
St                Street
```

i want to be able to replace the Address field in another table with the valules from the table above

so if i have an address 123 Main St - it should say 123 Main Street

if i have 123 Main Street - it should stay 123 Main Street, it shouldn't become 123 Main Streetreet

the table with addresses has a few million rows, is there a fast way of doing this?

thank you

Comment: Is it safe to assume that each address will have only one abbreviation in it which should be replaced?

Comment: no, it's not)))) there can be more than 1

Comment: Please let me know it this fits to you, then I will post as answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8b1e/1

Comment: If this is a one-time thing, Jorge has the right idea.  You should compose a regex of everything in your `NR_POSTAL_ABBR` table, and use that.

Comment: I respectfully submit that any solution to this problem is going to be slow. As you've indicated, a single row in the address table must be compared against all the rows in NR_POSTAL_ABBR (~400 rows), and each of these 400 checks must be done in such a way that it finds only abbreviations which are stand-alone and not part of other words. So you're going to do 400 * (number of addresses = some number of millions of rows) checks, which will almost certainly take a while. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis what about he do the replace with the regex I mentioned once and the put it into a trigger for the next inserts. Sure that will take a while the time it runs but then the time will only be for row per row.

Comment: I will be back at work in 45 mins and will try it. Thank you very much. Bob, I guess I was hoping for a solution that would replace multiple rows at once. Like to write a query with a replace statement that will replace correct parts for all records that have it. No way lol?

Comment: I just looked at Jorge's and it seems like that's what he did. Let me play around with it and I will post back.

Comment: How do I find out why the question got down voted

Comment: @Jorge Campos please post your answer, this is perfect!!!! and how do i find out why the question was downvoted?

Comment: I will post my code on Monday, I made a procedure that pulls the values from that table one by one. This is a nice and fast solution. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @lalachka As per Stackoverflow rules, you cannot see who upvoted or downvoted you, but it is common pratice to leave a comment explaining why you was downvoted, but not everyone do that. I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you asked. My suggestion is go through `regular expressions` So here is un update code for your case.

Suppose you have a table test with the field address, what you have to do is very simple, create an regular expression that match your requirements.

So: You need to replace every `St` for `Street` and `Av` for `Avenue` this is what you should do.

```
update test
   set address = 
   regexp_replace(
           regexp_replace(address, 'Av | Av$| Av ', ' Avenue ' ),
                           'St | St$| St ', ' Street ');
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8b1e/1) example

Explaining the regex:

The `regexp_replace` replaces a string for another based on a regular expression pattern, see the docs: [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

About the regular expressions you can see it here [Regular Expressions Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) Almost every language follow the `POSIX` pattern, so once you learn it you will be good.

So I've used to `regexp_replace` to achieve what you want because you gave two requirements. I will not write about the parameters of the function just the expressions.

At the first expression you have `'Av | Av$| Av '` which means: 
PS.: I put the `-` just to you see the space (**so ignore it**). SO wont let me put it.

`-Av -` (with a space at end) = Find every `Av` with a space after it on the string

`-|-` (pipe sign) = Equals an `or` statement

`- Av$-` = Find all `Av` with a space before it and when `Av` is at the end of the string. `$`

`- Av -` = Find all `Av` with a space before and a space after

Then The function replace any of theese ocurrences with the word `Avenue`. Notice that I put a space before and one after to avoid something like `Peer HarborAvenue`

The same explanation goes to `St` string

If you like the regular expressions function you can see more with it here: [Oracle Regular Expressions Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)

Answer (score 0):

just posting the automated version based on Jorge's reply, in case someone needs it.

```
    DECLARE
     ReplOrder NUMBER;
BEGIN
     ReplOrder := 1;


     DECLARE
       CURSOR getReplsStrng IS
         SELECT replacewhat
            ,replacewith
           FROM analyst.NR_POSTAL_ABBR
          WHERE ReplaceOrder = ReplOrder;
     BEGIN
       FOR getInnerRec IN getReplsStrng LOOP
         --        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('replace what ' || getInnerRec.replacewhat);
         --        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Replace Order ' || ReplOrder);


         UPDATE NR_TMP_106 tmp
            SET NewAddress = LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(NewAddress)
                                  ,   '$'
                                || getInnerRec.replacewhat
                                || ' | '
                                || getInnerRec.replacewhat
                                || '$| '
                                || getInnerRec.replacewhat
                                || ' '
                                  ,' ' || getInnerRec.replacewith || ' '))
          WHERE     1 = 1
             AND (   tmp.NewAddress LIKE '%' || CHR(32) || '' || getInnerRec.replacewhat || '' || NULL || '%'
                  OR tmp.NewAddress LIKE '%' || CHR(32) || '' || getInnerRec.replacewhat || '' || CHR(32) || '%'
                  OR tmp.NewAddress LIKE '%' || NULL || '' || getInnerRec.replacewhat || '' || CHR(32) || '%');

         COMMIT;
       END LOOP;
     END;


     ReplOrder := 2;


     DECLARE
       CURSOR getReplsStrng IS
         SELECT replacewhat
            ,replacewith
           FROM analyst.NR_POSTAL_ABBR
          WHERE ReplaceOrder = ReplOrder;
     BEGIN
       FOR getInnerRec IN getReplsStrng LOOP
         --        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('replace what ' || getInnerRec.replacewhat);
         --        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Replace Order ' || ReplOrder);


         UPDATE NR_TMP_106 tmp
            SET NewAddress = LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(NewAddress)
                                  ,   '$'
                                || getInnerRec.replacewhat
                                || ' | '
                                || getInnerRec.replacewhat
                                || '$| '
                                || getInnerRec.replacewhat
                                || ' '
                                  ,' ' || getInnerRec.replacewith || ' '))
                WHERE     1 = 1
                      AND (   tmp.NewAddress LIKE '%' || CHR(32) || '' || getInnerRec.replacewhat || '' || NULL || '%'
                           OR tmp.NewAddress LIKE '%' || CHR(32) || '' || getInnerRec.replacewhat || '' || CHR(32) || '%'
                           OR tmp.NewAddress LIKE '%' || NULL || '' || getInnerRec.replacewhat || '' || CHR(32) || '%');

         COMMIT;
       END LOOP;
     END;
END;
```